# emacs dispatch help window from original buffer

Tags: emacs

Whenever I do apropos, describe-key, or some other help function in emacs, it displays the help in my other window. In order to get rid of it, I must change windows/buffers to go there, type "q", and then change back to my original working buffer.

Is there a way I can do this in code somehow?  I know how to save-excursion, switch buffers, etc, but I don't know how to send the "q" to the minibuffer/emacs while I'm over in the other buffer. Thanks

Comment: The help buffer has `help-window-select` as noted below.  In general though, you might be interested in the shackle package (https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution to this problem.  I bind this command to `C-c q`:

```el
(defvar my/help-window-names
  '(
    ;; Ubiquitous help buffers
    "*Help*"
    "*Apropos*"
    "*Messages*"
    "*Completions*"
    ;; Other general buffers
    "*Command History*"
    "*Compile-Log*"
    "*disabled command*")
  "Names of buffers that `my/quit-help-windows' should quit.")

(defun my/quit-help-windows (&optional kill frame)
  "Quit all windows with help-like buffers.

Call `quit-windows-on' for every buffer named in
`my/help-windows-name'.  The optional parameters KILL and FRAME
are just as in `quit-windows-on', except FRAME defaults to t (so
that only windows on the selected frame are considered).

Note that a nil value for FRAME cannot be distinguished from an
omitted parameter and will be ignored; use some other value if
you want to quit windows on all frames."
  (interactive)
  (let ((frame (or frame t)))
    (dolist (name my/help-window-names)
      (ignore-errors
        (quit-windows-on name kill frame)))))
```

Comment: Interesting solution -- instead of talking to the buffer with "q", talk to Emacs and say "kill all these guys." And extensible too, which is nice. Thank you for contributing your code.

Answer (score 5):

The `help-window-select` variable might be exactly what you want.
If you set its value to true `(setq help-window-select t)` then the help window will automatically be selected when you open it via one of the help commands. You can then press `q` to quit out of it and go back to your original buffer. There are many other options so you should check those out too.

For the apropos window or any window that uses `display-buffer` you can use.

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         '("*Apropos*" display-buffer-same-window))
```

`display-buffer-same-window` is one options of many; it opens the buffer in the current window. The other possible options can be seen by looking up the docs on the `display-buffer` function.

Comment: Thank you for the fast, exactly-on-target reply!! We're halfway there. Setting the variable does indeed solve the problem for describe-key, but not for the Apropos displays. I checked for equivalent apropos variables (describe-variable apropos), but none of them looked like a help window selection.  Ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replay, I edited my answer with some info about the apropos buffer. I use a similar command for opening a shell in the same window as I currently am instead of in a different window. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jules. I guess it's better to have it cover my current buffer, since it's easy to dispatch that way. Better than having to go over there and type q... Thank you again.

Comment: @Kevin yeah, thats how I feel about it too, if you ever find a better way though, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting `(winner-mode 1)` in your init file, and then using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> to call `winner-undo` (repeatedly, if necessary) to return to a previous window configuration.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the tip. I already have winner mode.(But oddly enough, hardly ever use it, since old habits of ctrl-x o die hard...) There's lots of buffer/window magic that goes on under the hood in Emacs. I don't know why Apropos doesn't count as a help window -- it dispatches the same way (with a q). Oh well. I have something that works now, so on to other things.

Comment: Well `apropos-mode` and `help-mode` are distinct major modes. They are both derived from `special-mode` (which provides that keybinding), however.

Comment: YMMV, but I can only recommend getting more accustomed to utilising `winner-undo` (and maybe binding it to a slightly-easier key sequence, if that'll help). I find it absolutely invaluable as the generalised solution to all manner of problems similar to this one, as well as convenient for reverting window changes I've made intentionally.